# How to get WPF Window to autosize to content and no more

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, wpf-controls

I have a dialog containing 2 TextBlocks, a Progress Bar and a cancel Button.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="200">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="txtFirst" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap">This is a really really really really long string that wraps</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtSecond" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="5" Text="A Shorter string" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="200"/>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="prgProgress" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" Height="20" />
    <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5" Height="25" Width="50"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I would like the Window not to have a fixed height but auto adjust its height based on the size of its children and no more, but can’t see a way to do this. At the moment when I don’t assign anything to the Window’s height, it seems to adopt a height that is much bigger that the content.

Not sure why, or where it gets height value from? If I set Windows Height = “Auto” I get the same thing. All the heights for the RowDefinitions are set to “Auto”, which I take to mean ‘set row height to be row child height’.

Comment: what about Window `SizeToContent="Height"`?

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 104):

You need to use `SizeToContent` property, check the [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example:

```cs
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        …
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
```

Comment: I'm glad that SizeToContent works but would like to know why width="Auto" fails so badly. My window was nearly twice the width of the contents.